# Subsetting in python using multiple row ranges

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to plot a scatterplot using only data from rows 0 to 34 and 80 to 1001. I have tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
plt.scatter(df.iloc[[0:34, 80:101], 1], df.iloc[[0:34, 80:101], 0])
```

I have also tried doing it conditional, using index numbers, but I cannot refer to the index.

What is the way to do this?

Comment: can you post some sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html) for selecting multiple ranges at once:

Try this:

```
import numpy as np
plt.scatter(df.iloc[np.r_[0:34, 80:101], 1], df.iloc[np.r_[0:34, 80:101], 0])
```